# While dentro de outro While (PHP - SQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Dei uma buscada no forum e na internet, porem não consegui resolver o problema ainda! Eu estou fazendo uma consulta no banco pelo PHP e buscando usuarios. Depois que busco os usuarios eu busco as formações academicas dele dentro dessa outra busca (pois pode haver mais de uma) com isso o segundo while funciona apenas no primeiro usuario, no segundo em diante ele parece que "para".

Seguem meus codigos:

Busca usuarios

```
$query_busca_prof = "SELECT * FROM tags, user WHERE tag_tag LIKE '%$busca%' AND tag_user = user_id";
$Busca_busca_prof = mysql_query($query_busca_prof, $bd) or die(mysql_error());
$row_busca_prof = mysql_fetch_assoc($Busca_busca_prof);
$totalRows_busca_prof = mysql_num_rows($Busca_busca_prof);
```

Imprimir Usuarios e formação

```
do { 

    $query_busca_forma = "SELECT * FROM user_prof_forma WHERE user_prof_forma_user = '".$row_busca_prof['user_id']."'";
    $Busca_busca_forma = mysql_query($query_busca_forma, $bd) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_busca_forma = mysql_fetch_assoc($Busca_busca_forma);
    $totalRows_busca_forma = mysql_num_rows($Busca_busca_forma);

    echo $row_busca_prof['user_nome'];

    do {

        echo $row_busca_forma['user_formacao'];

      } while ($row_busca_forma = mysql_fetch_assoc($Busca_busca_forma)); // este que não funciona

} while($row_busca_prof = mysql_fetch_assoc($Busca_busca_prof));
```

Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Um join ou mais não mata esses whiles encadeados? Não use funções obsoletas ou vai ter o trabalho de atulizar o código depois.

Comment: parece que o erro esta no `while`, voce fala para realizar a ação quando for `=` ou seja, só 1x e ele vai ficar igual, tente substituir por `<` ou até mesmo fazer o while com uma contagem usando o `mysql_num_rows`

Comment: @rray não entendi muito bem o que você quis dizer!

Comment: Faça como o rray falou, se vc usar join vc pode evitar esses whiles desnecessários

Comment: vou colocar a resposta e voce confirma ok @LeonardoCarmo ?

Comment: Na sua variável "$query_busca_prof" está a consulta sql. Use join nela para vc evitar esses while, é lógico que vai ter que mudar o código acima...

Comment: @DiegodeSouzaSilva É que eu simplifiquei o html, então join nao iria resolver, porque a estrutura eu preciso que faça a impressão separadamente! Mas já entendi agora rs

Comment: @Leonardo, o rray quis dizer que um jeito mais apropriado é uma query SQL com JOIN (LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, etc.. ) . Assim eliminaria esses laços de repetição.

Comment: @DanielOmine entendi! E se eu colocar meus selects você acha que conseguiria me ajudar? Porque não sei como poderia fazer um unico select e trabalhar com html diferenciado para cada resultado depois, sendo que podem ser mais do que um

Comment: poste os selects aí.

Comment: @DanielOmine editei lá!

Comment: não entendi o trecho `'%$busca%' AND tag_user = user_id`. O campo `user_id` vem de onde? Não seria uma variável PHP?

Answer (score 3):

o comando `mysql_fetch_assoc()` é o comando que *adquire* um registro a partir de uma query executada. Ele precisa ser executado iterativamente:

```
while($row_busca_forma = mysql_fetch_assoc($Busca_busca_forma)){
    // Faça suas atividades aqui dentro
}
```

Seu código só funciona para o primeiro registro exatamente porque você só está executando o `mysql_fetch_assoc` apenas uma vez.

Leitura recomendada: [Por que não devo usar mysql_*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Comment: Obrigado pela recomendação, vou ler!

Answer (score 1):

Na realidade o Jeito correto de colocar várias linhas de uma busca dentro de um array, é com um while, dessamaneira:

```
$query_busca_prof = "SELECT ...";
$result= mysql_query($query_busca_prof, $bd) or die(mysql_error());    

$array_content = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ARRAY))
{
    $array_content[] = $row;
}
```

Do jeito que você está fazendo, você apenas pega a primeira linha e coloca no array, você pode checkar isso imprimindo o array em questão.

Comment: Utilizei desta forma mas não esta imprimindo nada!

Comment: @LeonardoCarmo no teu caso, você teria que fazer isso para os dois while que fez... É que agora estou no trabalho, mas vou reescrever o código para comportar melhor a tua situação.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você declara no seu `while($row_busca_forma = mysql_fetch_assoc($Busca_busca_forma)` ele só ira executar uma vez para que o resultado seja igual `=`, logo...ira parar a execução.

Tente colocar um sinal de menor ou igual `<=`, por exemplo;

`while($row_busca_forma <= mysql_fetch_assoc($Busca_busca_forma)`

Comment: Resolveu exatamente como eu precisava! Obrigado!

Comment: @LeonardoCarmo, marque como resposta correta por favor.

Comment: Preciso esperar 5m!

Comment: Agora que testei mais vi, na verdade não resolveu 100%! Se possui 2 registros ele não coloca os corretos, ele repete o mesmo duas vezes!